# Given $f(x)$ to be a continuous probability density function. Show that $\frac{1}{\sigma} f\big(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\big)$ is also a pdf.

Tags: probability, statistics

How do I prove this:

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous probability density function. Show that, for every $$- \infty < \mu < \infty $$ and $$\sigma > 0,$$  the function $$\frac{1}{\sigma} f\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$ is also a probability density function.

My Note:
As far as I know a function is a pdf of a continuous random variable is always nonnegative and $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f(x) \;dx= 1.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma}f\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$. As you point out, to show that $g$ is a density, you need to check that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\ dx = 1,$$
or
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma}f\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\ dx=1.$$
To show this, make the substitution $y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$. Then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sigma}$, and we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma}f\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma}f(y)\ \sigma dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y)\ dy = 1,$$
where the last equality follows from $f$ being a density.

Comment: Does this argument also follows that after the substitution I am ensured that  the f(y) is always positive?

Comment: @Ralf17 Yes, since $f$ is a density, you know that  $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In other words, no matter the input to $f$, be it $y$ or $\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ as in $f(y)$ or $f(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$, the result will always be non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You need to prove that if $g(x)=\frac1\sigma f(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) dx = 1$

To do that, apply a change of variables to the integral of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition of positiveness is almost trivial, whereas we must also check

$$I:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1\sigma f\left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)dx$$

But a simple change of variables do the trick:

$$t:=\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\implies \sigma\,dt=dx\implies I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1\sigma f(t)\,\sigma dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,dt=1$$